# Existence of an embedding?

Tags: graph-theory, model-theory, first-order-logic

Let $\mathcal{L}=\{R\}$ a language of the first order. We consider the set of graphs (which are irreflixive and symmetric). Then we define for a graph $G$ the following property $P$ : for $S_1$ and $S_2$ finite and disjoint $\subseteq G$, there exists $z\in G$ such that for all $x\in S_1$, $y\in S_2$ we have $R(x,z)$ and $\neg R(y,z)$. We denote $T$ the first order theory which satisfies these three properties.

First, I proved that there exists a countable model. Then I must prove that for a countable graph $K$ and a model $\mathcal{H}=(H,R)$ of $T$ (not necessary countable) I can find an embedding between $K$ and $H$.

Here is my attempt : I think that if $K$ could satisfy $P$, I could find an embedding between $K$ (which would become a countable model of $T$) and $\mathcal{H}$ by Lowenheim-Skolem. That means that every countable graph satisfies $P$.

First thing I noticed is that if $K$ is a countable graph with the property of irreflexivity I can find a least $2$ elements in $K$ such that $R(x_1,x_2)$. After, maybe I can use the fact that I can find an injective map $\iota$ between $\{x_1\}$ and a bigger finite set $\{\iota(x_1),...,\iota(x_k)\}$ which respects $\bigwedge_{1\le j\le k} R(\iota(x_j),x_2)$ (I'm not sure for $x_2$) . How can I arrive to the second part of the property $P$. Or maybe it's not the right way to proceed.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a minor comment: the first line of your last paragraph is incorrect - a countable irreflexive graph might have no edges at all!

OK, now the real answer: *work in stages*. (This is an intuition similar to that behind the *back-and-forth method* for building an isomorphism between appropriate countable structures, if you've seen that before.) Specifically, what you want is an embedding $f: K\rightarrow H$. $K$ is countable, so let $K=\{k_0, k_1, k_2, . . .\}$ (I'm assuming WLOG that $K$ is infinite, for notational simplicity). So let's build $f$ in stages!

Let $G_n$ be the subgraph of $K$ consisting of $\{k_0, k_1, . . . , k_n\}$. A *stage $n$ embedding* will be an embedding $f_n$ of $G_n$ into $H$. In order to build $f$, what do we need? Well,

- for each $n$, a stage $n$ embedding $f_n$

would be nice. But we want to be able to "glue" the $f_n$s together, so we also want

- $f_n(k_i)=f_m(k_i)$ whenever $i\le m, n$.

> Do you see why if we have such a set of $f_n$s, the map $\bigcup f_n$ is an embedding from $K$ into $H$?

OK, now let's build our $f_n$s. On the face of it, this might seem hard; however, the point of $T$ is that any model of $T$ "looks the same everywhere," so no matter how we've defined $f_n$, it will always be possible to extend it to $f_{n+1}$.

Here's a sketch of why: suppose I've defined $f_{17}$ - so I have an embedding from $G_{17}$ to $H$. Now I want to extend this to also include $k_{18}$. Bad news: I have to be careful where I send $k_{18}$! Maybe $k_{18}$ is connected to $k_1, k_3, k_{11},$ and $k_{16}$, and not connected to all the other $k_i$s (for $i<18$).

> Why is there some $h\in H$ such that $h$ is connected to $f_{17}(k_1), f_{17}(k_3), f_{17}(k_{11})$, and $f_{17}(k_{16})$, and not connected to $f_{17}(k_i)$ for any other $i<18$?
>
> Do you see how to use this to define $f_{18}$?

Comment: The existence of $h$ comes from the fact that $H$ has the property $P$ ?

Comment: @Maman Yes, do you see why?

Comment: I think it's because an embedding preserves first order formulas. One thing, we have directly that $G_n$ is embed in $H$ because of cardinality ?

Comment: @Maman No, that's not true. First of all, embeddings *don't* preserve first-order formulas: we can embed a 2-element graph into a 3-element graph, but "there are exactly 2 elements" is a first-order property. Embeddings preserve *quantifier-free* formulas. Second, no - you can't just deduce that from cardinality (for example, a graph with two vertices and one edge doesn't embed into a graph with infinitely many vertices and no edges). I think you're trying to prove this too quickly: look at what you want, and at property $P$, and see how you can apply property $P$.

Comment: I have $G_{17}=\{k_1,...,k_{17}\}$ and an embedding $f_{17} : G_{17} \to H$. We want to extend it to the set $G_{18}=\{k_1,...,k_{17},k_{18}\}$. I must send $k_{18}$ knowing that $H$ has the property $P$. The property $P$ says that for all two disjoint finite ($H_1$, $H_2$) sets I can find an element from $H$ such that $h$ is related to all the elements of $H_1$ and none of $H_2$.

Comment: @Maman No, property $P$ says that *for any* disjoint finite sets $H_1, H_2$ you can find such an element of $H$. Now, what do you think you should take to be your $H_1$ and $H_2$?

Comment: I want to send $f_{17}(k_{1,3,11,16})$  on $H_1$. With irreflexivity I could define a new element $h=k_{18}$ which is not in $H_1$ and $H_2$ (this new element will be different from all).

Comment: @Maman I think you're misunderstanding "irreflexivity" - that just means that no element is connected to itself. The point is that property $P$ guarantees that there is some $h\in H$ such that $h$ is connected to $k_1, k_3, k_{11},$ and $k_{16}$, and is not connected to the other $k_i$s. Do you see why?

Comment: I am a little confused. It would mean that $h$ is in $H_1$

Comment: @Maman . . . What? How would it mean that $h$ is in $H_1$? $H_1$ is the set $\{f_{17}(k_1), f_{17}(k_3), f_{17}(k_{11}), f_{17}(k_{16})\}$. The element $h$ we want - and which is guaranteed by property $P$ - is **connected to** each element of $H_1$. How do you conclude that it *is* some element of $H_1$? I think you are misunderstanding property $P$: it says just that given a bunch of vertices $A$, and a bunch of different vertices $B$, I can find some vertex connected to all the $A$-vertices but none of the $B$-vertices.

Comment: If $f_{17}$ is an embedding does it preserve the property $P$ ? Because there is universal quantifier

Comment: @Maman What do you mean "preserves the property $P$"? $H$ has property $P$; $K$ probably doesn't. The problem is asking: "If $H$ has property $P$ and $K$ is *any countable graph*, show that $K$ embeds into $H$." It is irrelevant whether $K$ has property $P$; the only place you use $P$ is to figure out how to extend $f_{17}$ to $f_{18}$, that is, where to send $k_{18}$ given where you've already sent $k_1$ through $k_{17}$. I think you should go back and re-read the problem to make sure you understand what it is asking.

Comment: Indeed I begin with graph theory so it's not fluent for me. I restart, we want to extend $G_{17}$ to $G_{18}$ in the aim to build $f_{18}$. We define an embedding $f_{17} : G_{17}\to H$. We suppose that $k_{18}$ is just connected to $k_{1,3,11,16}$. We send them to $f_{17}(k_{1,3,11,16})$ in $H$. We know that $H$ satisfies $P$ so there exists $h$ which is is connected to all the elements of $H_1$ and non of $H_2$ (for all  finite disjoint subset of $H$). How can I be sure that $h$ is just connected to $f_{17}(k_{1,3,11,16})$ ? After I could extend $f_{17}$ to $f_{18}$ and conclude by reunion.

Comment: @Maman *By applying $P$.* Remember what $P$ says: "Given any two disjoint finite subsets $A, B$ of $H$, there is an $h\in H$ connected to everything in $A$ and connected to nothing in $B$." So take $A=\{f(k_1), f(k_3), f(k_{11}), f(k_{16})\}$ and $B=\{f(k_2), f(k_4, . . .\}$ (the other $f(k_i)$s). Do you see why $A$ and $B$ are disjoint? So by property $P$, we have some $h\in H$ such that . . .

Comment: The property of being an embedding ($f_{17}$ here) gives the two disjoints sets

Comment: I have the feeling that we admit that each $f_{n}: G_{n} \to H$ was an embedding.

Comment: Moreover what could I take for $f_0$ ? $f_0= \emptyset$ ?

Comment: @Maman Re: your first comment, yes. We're building $f_n$ by *induction*, assuming we already have $f_{n-1}$. Re: your second question, not quite; $f_0$ has to already decide where to send $k_0$. Fortunately, we can just take $f_0$ to send $k_0$ to anything in $H$; there are no restrictions on where $k_0$ should go. Does that make sense? Intuitively, think of this as beginning at $f_{-1}=\emptyset$. (Or re-index so that $f_n$ tells me where to send $k_i$ for $i<n$, instead of $i\le n$; then indeed we begin with $f_0=\emptyset$.)

Comment: Thank you for the patience, I start to understand the trick

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Enumerate the vertices of $K$. Then use the extension property (property $P$) to embed $K$ in $H$ one vertex at a time: if $f$ is the embedding map, when you embed vertex $v_n$, there is a vertex $v$ in $H$ such that for all $k<n$, $R(f(v_k),v)$ if and only if $R_K(v_k,v_n)$.